# Show $\int_{X} \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{k} d\mu \leq \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{X} f_{k} d\mu$ when $f_{k} \geq g$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I have been reading the book "Modern Real Analysis" by Ziemer and have come to an exercise I'm having trouble with. The exercise is in the chapter on integration and the section on limit theorems. The exercise statement goes :

> Suppose $\{ f_{k} \}$ is a sequence of measurable functions, $g$ is a
> $\mu$-integrable function, and $f_{k} \geq g$ $\mu$-a.e. for each $k$. Show that :
> \begin{equation}
> \int_{X} \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{k} d\mu \leq \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{X} f_{k} d\mu
> \end{equation}

Here $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is the measure space and $f_{k} : X \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and $g : X \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ where
$\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is the extended real numbers.

Here are some results from the text of the chapter.

> Theorem 6.9 :
> If $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function and $g$ is an integrable function, then :
> \begin{equation}
> \underline{\int_{X}} (f+g) d\mu = \overline{\int_{X}}(f+g)d\mu = \int_{X} f d\mu + \int_{X} g d\mu
> \end{equation}

> Lemma 6.12 (Fatou's Lemma)
> If $\{ f_{k} \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of nonnegative $\mu$-measurable functions,
> then :
> \begin{equation}
> \int_{X} \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{k} d\mu \leq \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{X} f_{k} d\mu
> \end{equation}

Below is my current attempt at a solution :

Let $N \in \mathcal{M}$ be the null set for which $f_{k}(x) \geq g(x) \; \forall x \in X \setminus N$.
Let's first assume $N = \emptyset$. So in this case $f_{k} \geq g \; \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Let :
\begin{equation}
h_{k} = f_{k} - g \; \forall k \in \mathbb{N}
\end{equation}
So $h_{k} \geq 0 \; \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. So by lemma 6.12 :
\begin{equation} 
\int_{X} \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} h_{k} d\mu \leq \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{X} h_{k} d \mu
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
But :
\begin{align}
\liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} h_{k}(x) 
 & = \sup_{j \geq 1} \left[ \inf_{k \geq j} f_{k}(x) - g(x) \right]\\
 & = \sup_{j \geq 1} \left[ \inf_{k \geq j} f_{k}(x) \right] - g(x) \\
 & = \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{k}(x) - g(x)
\end{align}
We see :
\begin{align}
\int_{X} f_{k} d\mu 
 & = \int_{X} (h_{k} + g) d \mu \\
 & = \int_{X} h_{k} d\mu + \int_{X} g d\mu
\end{align}
by theorem 6.9 since $h_{k} \geq 0$ and $g$ is integrable.

So :
\begin{equation}
\int_{X} h_{k} d\mu = \int_{X} f_{k} d\mu - \int_{X} g d\mu
\end{equation}
and :
\begin{align}
\eqref{1} 
 & \Rightarrow \int_{X} \left( \left[ \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{k} \right] - g \right) d\mu \leq \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left[ \int_{X} f_{k} d\mu - \int_{X} g d\mu \right] \\
 & \Rightarrow \int_{X} \left( \left[ \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{k} \right] - g \right) d\mu \leq \left[ \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{X} f_{k} d\mu \right] - \int_{X} g d\mu 
\end{align}
So if :
\begin{equation} \
\int_{X} \left( \left[ \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{k} \right] - g \right) d\mu \leq \int_{X} \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{k} d\mu - \int_{X} g d\mu
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation}
then :
\begin{equation}
\eqref{1} \Rightarrow \int_{X} \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{k} d\mu \leq \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{X} f_{k} d \mu
\end{equation}
and we are done. So need to prove \eqref{2}.

Here my idea is to first assume the null set on which $f_{k} \geq g$ may not hold is empty to simplify things. Can anyone help with this ? I've also noticed that many results in the text require the assumption that various measurable functions are nonnegative.
Is there any routine way to try to generalize such results to measurable functions that are not necessarily nonnegative (possibly by adding additional assumptions about the funtion).

Comment: Why and who are downvoting?. The op has shown his/her work and wants help.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron: This is a duplicate of other questions already answered in the past. I did not vote (-1) however.

Comment: @OliverDíaz The point is that the op has pretty much nailed the proof of this "generalization" of Fatou's Lemma, but is confused about the "a.e." part and how to move from pointwise criteria to the almost everywhere criteria. So just suggesting the op to a proof of the lemma which does not elaborate on his point of confusion would yield nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Integral over a measure $0$ set is $0$. If $N$ is the set where $f_{k}\ngeq g$ then  $\int_{X} \phi\,d\mu$ for **ANY** measurable function $\phi$ is the same as $\int_{X\setminus N}\phi\,d\mu$ . So it suffices to show that your conclusion holds when the null set is the empty set.

This is ofcourse when you provide an argument to find a single set $N$ for which $f_{k}\geq g$ for **ALL** $k$. To do that you pick the sets $N_{j}$ for each $j$ of measure $0$ outside of which $f_{j}\geq g$. Then outside the set $\bigcup_{j\in\Bbb{N}}N_{j}$ , you have $f_{k}\geq g$ for all $k$. And $\mu(\bigcup_{j\in\Bbb{N}}N_{j}) = 0$ by the countable subadditivity .

Now you call $N=\bigcup_{j\in\Bbb{N}}N_{j}$ .

And by what you have done for the case when $N=\phi$. You have for  $(X\setminus N,\mathcal{F}\bigg|_{X\setminus N} ,\mu\bigg|_{X\setminus N})$ , the restricted space the result is true. And since the integrals over $X$ are the same as integrals over $X\setminus N$ , you have the result when $N\neq \phi$.